# How to get zoomed Bitmap from original bitmap using RectF Bouunds

Tags: bitmap

I want to show only zoomed part of image using RectF bounds from orignal bitmal.

below is my sample code

```
fun getZoomedBitmap(orignalBitmap: Bitmap,zoomedRectF: RectF) : Bitmap{
    val zoomMatrix =  Matrix()
    val scaleX = orignalBitmap.width / zoomedRectF.width()
    val scaleY = orignalBitmap.height / zoomedRectF.height()
    val translateX = -zoomedRectF.left * scaleX
    val translateY = -zoomedRectF.top * scaleY
    zoomMatrix.setScale(scaleX,scaleY)
    zoomMatrix.postTranslate(translateX,translateY)
    val zoomBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(zoomedRectF.width().toInt(),zoomedRectF.height().toInt(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(zoomBitmap)
    canvas.drawBitmap(orignalBitmap,zoomMatrix,null)
    return zoomBitmap;
}
```